# Variance of nonlinear regression coefficient

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, variance

hopefully simple questions

From a regression model $y=B_1(x^2)$ and

$$B_1 = \frac{\sum{(Y\times X^2)}}{\sum(X^4)}$$

Please calculate the variance of this regression coefficient ... I'm not sure how to proceed with the summations inside, and with the $X$s, etc.... also does this ultimately equal $Cov(X, Y)/Var(X)$ like a typical regression model, or is it something different?

Comment: Where you get B1, I get $\frac{\sum Y}{\sum x^2}$

Comment: I don't believe you can divide sum of x^2 into sum of x^4

Comment: how did you get B1.

Answer (score 2):

For the model $E(Y|x)=\beta x^2$, with $\text{Var}(Y|x)=\sigma^2$*, the least squares estimate is indeed

$\hat\beta = \sum_i(y_ix^2_i)/\sum_i x^4_i$

as you suggest.

* (though we don't need that to derive the OLS estimator, we need a variance assumption to compute the variance of it)

Derivation of this estimate is straightforward, so I won't labor the point by reproducing your work on it; for example, we can see it by letting $z=x^2$ and taking the ordinary least squares line through the origin for the regression of $y$ on $z$.

Similarly, we can compute the variance using the same substitution.

Again let $z=x^2$ and use the ordinary least squares variance (which can be found readily enough even if you can't derive it):

$\text{Var}(Y|z)=\frac{1}{(z'z)^2}\text{Var}(z'y)=\frac{1}{(z'z)^2}z'\text{Var}(y)z=\frac{\sigma^2}{(z'z)^2}z'z=\frac{\sigma^2}{(z'z)}=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_i z_i^2}\,.$

And from there we can simply substitute $z_i=x_i^2$ again.

Of course, we need to estimate $\sigma^2$, but that's done in the usual manner from the residuals, keeping in mind we have only one parameter here.